# How to create a search field on swift code by using firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to do an iOS app with two auth level using firebase.
The second auth must be validate by insert on a text field a code witch is located in databse.

[json root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luGts.png)

```
//
//  AccessoTerzoLivello.swift
//  amesci
//
//  Created by Gianluca Caliendo on 07/07/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Amesci. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class AccessoTerzoLivello: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var CodiceVolontarioTxt: UITextField!

  @IBAction func Accedi(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var rootRef: DatabaseReference!

    rootRef = Database.database().reference()

    var conditionalRef = rootRef.child("SchedaVolontari")

    conditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in }

    if self.CodiceVolontarioTxt.text = snap

    }
    else {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Codice volontario non valido", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check [how-to-use](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of SO and update your question. Also provide details what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way. There is a problem with your line:

`if self.CodiceVolontarioTxt.text = snap`

`Snap` is a dictionary which holds your codes, you can't compare it to your text input. First of all you have to get all the codes from it.

Here is some code. I haven't tested this but it will give you an idea. Replace the if else statement in your completion block with this:

```
// This is empty array which will contain all the codes
var codesArray: NSMutableArray = []

// Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
let snapshotChildren = snap.children

// Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
  // Get code node key and save it to codes array
  codes.add(child.key)
}

// Compare if inserted text matches any code from database
if codesArray.contains(self.CodiceVolontarioTxt.text) {
  print("Code exists in Firebase")
} else {
  print("Code does not exist in Firebase")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help ZassX, the code have two issues: Value of type NSMutableArray has no member 'append'

Comment: @GianlucaCaliendo Sorry my bad, try with codesArray.add(child.getKey()). I have updated answer above.

Comment: Still an issue: "Value of type 'FIRDataSnapshot' has no member 'getKey'"

Comment: @GianlucaCaliendo Which Firebase version do you have? Try `key`instead of `getKey`. If it doesn't work, check out Firebase documentation you will find it in there.

Comment: I'm using the actual version of Firebase with the actual version of Swift code.

Comment: @GianlucaCaliendo Did you try changing `getKey` to `key`?

Comment: I solide, it was just an old segue that i forget to delete xD

Comment: there is just a last "bug" to solve... When i write an invalide code, he perform the segue anyway, why?

Comment: @GianlucaCaliendo Add `print(child.key)` inside while and print `self.CodiceVolontarioTxt.text` somewhere to check the values and see what goes wrong.

Comment: WE did it! thank you very much! (i linked the button to the viewcontroller indeed by the vc)